# how many times The cURL can send the information if it doesn't receive the response by web service?

Tags: php, curl, time

I use **cURL** (php) for send some information by a web service.

It sent usually one time the information but **sometime**, it sent **twice**.

So I checked the log by curl_getinfo.

**One time :**

```
[total_time]:::1.783 _____ s:10:"total_time";d:1.78299999999999993;s:15

[total_time]:::2.611

[total_time] :::3.751

total_time]:::5.967

total_time]:::6.643
```

**and when there are twice :**

```
[total_time]:::9.547 _____ s:10:"total_time";d:9.5470000000000006;
[total_time]:::8.656
[total_time]:::9.563
```

So here is my question : how many times The cURL can send the information if it doesn't receive the response by web service ?
what period does it apply? 
How I can adjust this time ?

I would like that my script waits at least 11 second before try to send second time: How can I do?

here is my code :

```
/*
etc bla bla
*/

$myPhpCurl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($myPhpCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $url_ws);
curl_setopt($myPhpCurl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($myPhpCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($myPhpCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($myPhpCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('xml' => $send_xml_formed)));
curl_setopt($myPhpCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$execute = curl_exec($myPhpCurl);
$responseCURL = curl_getinfo($myPhpCurl);

$logFile = "\r\n" .'Information by CURL :'.  "\r\n" . serialize($responseCURL) . "\r\n" .'Response from ws :'."\n". $execute. "\r\n";
if(curl_errno($myPhpCurl))
{           
    $number_error = curl_errno($myPhpCurl);
    $txt_error = curl_error($myPhpCurl);
}
curl_close($myPhpCurl)

/* continue

*/
```

thanks and have a good weekend

Comment: I don't think curl retries automatically.

Comment: curl doesn't retry automatically!

Comment: curl doesn't, but the TCP protocol does! its possibly TCP not getting its ACK so it re-sends the packet a couple of times

Comment: Thanks hanshenrik, watashiwa Batman-desu,  

So you think that The protocol TCP/iP did not received the Acknowledges data (ACK), after SYN and FIN : more extension of time (>8 second), The TCP sent again.

How I can say to TCP : *wait pléase more 10 second* by php ?

Whit function sleep ? or I need another thinks ?

Comment: COULD  y o u   HELP  m e   PLEASE   f o r     THIS    T h a n k s

Comment: since there is no solution to this problem, I close the ticket, thank you and have a good day